# Gupshup integrated bot not working

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, gupshup

Gupshup integrated bot on messenger was working since 5 months suddenly it is not working for any page,but is working fine for Gupshup Proxy bot .

- I tried creating new page and integrated that page, but of no use.
- I edited a message to confirm if integration is properly working, it is working!!
- Tested it on GupShup proxy bot , working fine.

Comment: Can you provide more information as in -  mode of development of the bot on Gupshup and steps taken to publish etc.  Because I just tested and the bot is working on messenger

Answer (score 0):

I believe your page access token has expired because of one of the following reason:

1. You no longer have admin rights on the Facebook page.
2. You have changed your Facebook account password.

If you still have admin rights on the page, generate a new page access token from the Facebook App and submit the same on Gupshup platform.

Refer to deploy section of this guide:
https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/build-deploy-test-bots-on-messenger